# Scroll vertical por partes

Tags: javascript, html, css

me gustaria saber como programar con html,css y js .un scroll personalizado 
Que pase de la portada a la siguiente página con un solo movimiento de ruleta de ratón.
Esto es lo que quiero
http://jsfiddle.net/t6LLybx8/1118/

Y repetir con todas las secciones, para hacer asi la web mas usable.

Podeis ayudarme?
Esta es la imagen donde cargo los js y css, el js lo cargo desde modo.js
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
(function() {
  var delay = false;

  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }
    
    if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
      });
    }
  });
})();
console.clear();
```

```css
a{
display:block;
}
```

```html
    
     <a name="#A1"></a>
     Hola
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque arcu odio, mollis sit amet volutpat nec, pharetra hendrerit justo. Fusce vel sodales sem. Vivamus tincidunt nibh vitae augue convallis sodales quis in odio. In ullamcorper dapibus varius. Suspendisse placerat dictum sapien, a ultrices justo pretium ut. Pellentesque lectus leo, condimentum eget tristique at, vestibulum a ligula. Maecenas dignissim lacus magna. Sed elementum tempor justo. Vestibulum porta condimentum justo, ut volutpat turpis molestie nec. Donec nec dictum neque. Morbi sapien quam, porttitor nec magna a, viverra venenatis est. Donec a urna sit amet tellus volutpat accumsan eu in purus. Fusce tristique dui vitae ligula molestie, sit amet sodales erat dignissim. Maecenas efficitur sagittis hendrerit. Maecenas in orci diam.</p>
     <hr>
    <a name="#A2"></a>
    adios
    
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque arcu odio, mollis sit amet volutpat nec, pharetra hendrerit justo. Fusce vel sodales sem. Vivamus tincidunt nibh vitae augue convallis sodales quis in odio. In ullamcorper dapibus varius. Suspendisse placerat dictum sapien, a ultrices justo pretium ut. Pellentesque lectus leo, condimentum eget tristique at, vestibulum a ligula. Maecenas dignissim lacus magna. Sed elementum tempor justo. Vestibulum porta condimentum justo, ut volutpat turpis molestie nec. Donec nec dictum neque. Morbi sapien quam, porttitor nec magna a, viverra venenatis est. Donec a urna sit amet tellus volutpat accumsan eu in purus. Fusce tristique dui vitae ligula molestie, sit amet sodales erat dignissim. Maecenas efficitur sagittis hendrerit. Maecenas in orci diam.</p>
    <hr>
```

Comment: Cree que si pretendes que te ayuden, deberías mostrar lo que has conseguido, imagino que ya habras  [echo el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Suerte.

Answer (score 2):

Para la maquetación del scroll puedes fijarte en este plugin:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html#examples

Ejemplo básico:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Una vez tengas tu scroll puedes jugar con la función `scroll` de `jQuery` o directamente con javascript puro. En estos dos enlaces hablan de:

1.- Hacer el scroll a un anchor determinado (en ese caso con un evento click)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/how-to-scroll-up-or-down-the-page-to-an-anchor-using-jquery

2.- Saber si el scroll es hacia arriba o hacia abajo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957860/detect-user-scroll-down-or-scroll-up-in-jquery

Te dejo un fiddle modificado que mezcla ambos enlaces. El ejemplo hace un scroll a sendos anchors de la página según hagas scroll hacia arriba o hacia abajo. En tu caso tendrás que buscar el `offset` y según dónde estés ir a un anchor u otro.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/BjpWB/5765/

Comment: No todas las preguntas pueden o deben responderse. Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro o que no contienen suficiente información son un ejemplo de ello. Debería esperarse a que el usuario edite la pregunta y aclare/añada información antes de responder. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Kiko_L , me has dado información de como funciona el scroll, pero mis conocimientos son limitados, he encontrado este ejemplo que es exactamente lo que necesito, http://jsfiddle.net/t6LLybx8/728/ pero cuando lo implemento en mi web no funciona como esperaba, no me coge reconoce correctamente los anchor y no reacciona bien al scroll. Para usarlo he insertado el js, y he creado los <a name="#A2">Tag #2.</a> donde han sido pertinentes ¿falta algo más?

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema? Acabo de crear este fiddle con el código editado que has puesto y funciona sin problemas: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/8mvLcrmb/1/

Comment: Me escupe este error: 5(index):210 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):210) at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3) at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3) He leido que puede ser porque esa versión de jquery no tenga todos los parámetros necesarios ¿dónde puedo obtener una versión complete de jquery? Ahora estoy usando esta version <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: La versión de jQuery es completa. El "min" es de "minified" que quiere decir que es una versión comprimida. Eliminan saltos de líneas, espacios en blanco y demás caracteres que ocupan espacio para que sea más ligero el archivo. No obstante, he probado con esa versión y funciona sin problemas así que el problema tiene que ser otro: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/8mvLcrmb/2/

Comment: El error persistía por el caché, he probado en mozilla y no aparece el error, parece que el chrome no refresca bien el cache. Ahora me da el siguiente error TypeError: a[i].getClientRects(...)[0] is undefined ... algo no deja que funcione bien el código.

Comment: ¿En qué orden cargas los javascripts? ¿Puedes enseñarnos el html donde cargas los javascripts?

Comment: Sí, te adjunto la imagen. El error aparece cada vez que hago scrollWheel, ya sea hacia arriba o hacia abajo y no me realiza el scroll